# How can I run my MPI code with several nodes?

Tags: mpi, cluster-computing, nodes, rocks

I have a ROCKS Cluster with 1 frontend and 2 nodes (compute-0-1, compute-0-4) and. I can run my code only in frontend but when I try to run my code whit the nodes of many ways:

[output by console of frontend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDsQs.png)

It always returns me:

```
mpirun was unable to launch the specified application as it could not find an executable
```

- machine_file is located in default path and I tried to put it in a path of my project and contains:

compute-0-1
compute-0-4

¿What am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked the [docs](http://www.rocksclusters.org/roll-documentation/hpc/5.5/using_openmpi.html)? They say you cannot run as root. Also make sure that the program you want to run is present on all the nodes, and try calling it by absolute rather than relative path.

Comment: You are probably not using a shared filesystem like NFS. In that case, you have to copy the executable into the same location on all compute nodes and make sure all libraries it depends on are present there too.